# move one row to the end of a result set in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to move a row to the bottom of the result set given a matched condition.

### Database

```
+-------+------------+
|Symbol | Percentage |
|-------|------------|
|VG     | 20         |
|-------|------------|
|CASH   | 20         |
|-------|------------|
|GOOG   | 60         |
+-------+------------+
```

ex:
`SELECT * FROM TableName -SEND TO END OF RESULT SET- WHERE symbol = 'CASH'`

result set:

```
GOOG
VG
CASH
```

---

### To clarify my original question...

I need to write an exception for an `ORDER BY` statement.  To put the query into plain english - `SELECT` an entire row, ordering by a timestamp, except if the symbol is "CASH"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To change the order of the rows in a result set you should use ORDER BY:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
ORDER BY symbol = 'CASH', timestamp
```

Comment: nice ...
but maybe it should be "ORDER BY (symbol='CASH'), timestamp" (or something) so the order of the other rows will be deterministic.

Comment: @Ollie Jones: You are right - the question was changed since I posted my answer. I've updated it now.