# how to move a particular row of ResultSet to the End of it in MSSQL?

Tags: java, row, move, resultset

My question is : I want to move a particular row to the end of a MSSQL resultset in java.
How can this be done ? I found a reference in MySQL at link [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604568/move-one-row-to-the-end-of-a-result-set-in-mysql)

But, it didn't work for me since I'm using MSSQL2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to do something like

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN column = 'value' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Not sure about the exact SQL Server specific syntax, but something like this usually works.

Comment: Thank you Mark for the answer. Actually I used exact the same way you answered, but slightly different case values to meet my requirements.

Answer (score -1):

A bit of detail as to exacly what you want to do might help in answering the question, but the most coomon way of doing this, would be using the "order by" clause in your sql, and let the database sort the resultset for you. For a more correct or complete answer, I think we need to know a little more about your problem. But I hope this at least gets you started.

Comment: Thanks vruum for the answer. But the Order By clause can not fulfil my requirement. Since I have to position a nth row to the last of the ResultSet to behave it exactly as if were the last row in the ResultSet. Further suggestions are welcome.

Comment: A resultset doesn't really work that way. It's more like a pointer to a row, in a table the database generated as a response to your query, which can be incremented(and sometimes decremented) . it can't be sorted or ordered, and although some resultsets are updateable and supports inserts/updates, this is driver specific.
see [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html#rs_update)
So, your best bet is to either use sql that does the ordering for you, or sort the results in clientcode.

Comment: thank you vruum for the active answers. I'm sorry for that somebody downvoted for your previous answer. I've done the solution of my problem by now.